# How to see the sequence of Windows API calls in Ida Pro (Freeware Version)?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

Currently when trying to get an overview of what an executable is doing, I manually scan through the code in Ida Pro, using the Windows API calls as the main indicator of what's happening.

I'm wondering is there a way (doesn't have to be Ida Pro) to get a sequential list of the Windows API calls in order of use? I understand this would probably look like a tree, but at least I will be able to quickly get an overview of what the executable is doing.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The most similar view to what you are talking about is [proximity-browser](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/new-feature-in-ida-6-2-the-proximity-browser/).

[image]